# copying and highlighting text in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project that involves copying text from an iframe to a popup and then highlighting the entire copied text with any of the three given colors for highlighting and then reflect this highlighted text with the highlight back to the iframe and save it any idea how to do???

Comment: yes use javascript :)

Comment: First of you should provide some code. Anyway, I think you're looking for [mark.js](https://markjs.io) sInce it has iframe support.

Comment: Thanks for that! I am aware but i am a newbie in js! i have successfully copied the text from the iframe to the popup and added a background color based on the highlight selector, how do i reflect back to the iframe? i want something like http://mir3z.github.io/texthighlighter/demos/iframe.html but color selection would be after copying the text to a popup and not by default like

Comment: you can use rangy.js

Comment: i need it to work on iframe!